# NGInx log_format remove any sensitive data from $http_referrer

Tags: nginx, logging, nginx-config

I'm looking to sanitize `$http_referrer` url when it contains credit card number before it is logged into `access.log`. My goal is to avoid to capturing CC-Numbers into access.log.

In the below sample URL, it has CC-Number:

Before Sanitization: https://example.com?cc_number=402312123416781

After Sanitization Expected URL : https://example.com

---

Below is my NGinx conf:

```
map $http_referrer $sanitized_http_referrer {
 default $http_referer;

 # sanitize referrer URL, remove query params if url contains any sensitive information like 
 # CC number 
 "need help" "";

}


http {
   # As shown below I'm able to manipulate `log_format` 
   # but, I don't know how to sanitize CC-Number before it gets into log

   log_format sanitize_referrer '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
       '"$request_uri" $status $body_bytes_sent '
       '"$sanitized_http_referrer" "$http_user_agent"';
}

server {
            access_log /var/logs/access.log sanitize_referrer
}
```

---

Please provide any inputs, how to sanitize or remove all query params **only when it contains CC-Number in the URL**.

Comment: Try: `~*^(?<referrer>.*)[?].*cc_number   $referrer;`

Comment: @RichardSmith not working as expected, do I need to use `$referrer` or `$http_referrer` from the above regex.

Comment: My comment replaces the `"need help" "";` line. The rest of your map remains the same. `$http_referrer` is a predefined variable. `$referrer` is the named capture from my regular expression. You can call it anything as long as it's not already used by Nginx; I thought `referrer` was a safe name to use.